# Mod_rewrite engine enabled slows my dedicated beast of a box to a crawl

Tags: performance, apache, mod-rewrite, timeout

I've been troubleshooting an issue with `.htaccess` on a script that I've purchased and it's causing me quite a bit of strife.  If I have rewrite enabled and use Blitz.io for a 1-250 test, it get's to about 5 users before timing out on all requests.  There is no server resource contention that I can see, when this event occurs, yet I do on occasion see the event from Apache that I've used the maximum connections up. This can't be right as I've set it to handle several thousand connections.

Further backing up the rewrite theory, if I disable rewrite and run a Blitz against the same php page it completes the test without errors or timeouts of any significance (it also breaks most of the script :)).  I also notice that my response time in Blitz with rewrite off is about 250ms max, whereas if I enable the rewrite engine it shoots up to past one second.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I've searched quite a bit an haven't come up with much, granted I'm a re-write n00b.

Thanks in advance, going to go ice my head now...

```
    # enable apache morRewrite module #
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    # set files headers
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|js|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|htc)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    # allow request methods
    <Limit POST PUT DELETE GET OPTIONS HEAD>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from All
    </Limit>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

    # non last slash redirect
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.php|\.html|\.xml|\.txt|[\/])$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [NC,L,R=301]

     # define system languages
    #RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

    # define paging
    RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.*)?/index([0-9]*).ht(m?ml?)$ index.php?           page=$1&rlVareables=$2&pg=$3 [QSA,L]

    # define listing
    RewriteRule ^(([\w\-\_]+)?/)(.+)-l?([0-9]+).ht(m|ml)$ index.php? page=$2&rlVareables=$3&listing_id=$4 [QSA,L]

    # wildcard request
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.|m\.|mobile\.).*)\..+\.[^/]+$ [NC]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.|m\.|mobile\.).*)\..+$ [NC] # FIRST LEVEL         DOMAIN (localhost) USAGE
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=%1&wildcard&rlVareables=$1 [QSA,L]

    # account request (sub-directory)
    RewriteRule ^((\w{2})/)?([\w-_]{3,})$ index.php?page=$3&lang=$2&account_request [QSA,L]

    # define single pages
    RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(^/*)?.ht(m?ml?)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

    # define other pages
    RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.*)?/?(.*)?(.ht(m?ml?)|/+)$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Those rules don't make sense. E.g. the stray `RewriteCond ...`'s before ErrorDocument, without a RewriteRule! Does the site even work with those rewriterules?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at your access logs and rewrite.logs (if you can temporarily enable the latter)?

One thing that does jump out is the Header directive for your furniture (css, jpegs, etc.)  and specifically the must revalidate flag.  This will force client browsers to issue a conditional GET for every image etc.  This is not the default behaviour.   Browsers will assume a cacheable life of 10% of the age of any static file (that is if it is 10weeks old, the browser will only revalidate the file once per week).  OK most of these GETs will result in 304 "not modified" response, but this still means that Apache has to validate these requests, and this could easily increase the overall request rate to your server by 5-10x.

The "non last slash redirect" will fire for all URIs other than php, html, xml and txt files including jpeg's etc.  The two REQUEST_FILENAME conditions should immediately precede the REQUEST_URI condition.  Viz the ErrorDocument directive needs to be moved up 4 lines.

You also need to use test vectors to check out the single and other page regexps.  They are valid syntax but won't give you what I think you want (e.g. `[^//]` is the same as `[^/]`; `.ht(m?ml?)` matches `shtmml`;  the ^/* should probably read `[^/]*` so this rule currently only matches if `^([^//]+)/?` matches to the null string and thus degenerates to `(^/*)?.ht(m?ml?)$`.

I'd ask for my money back if I were you :-(